# how to put php variable in add filter function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce, this function is used to display products per page so that it returns some value that much of products are going to show in one page in front end.

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return 10' ), 20 );
```

This function returns 10 products per page. but instead of 10 i need to put a php variable that carries a value like this but it is not working

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return $perpage' ), 20 );
```

How can I return that value as a PHP variable?

Answer (score 0):

The function you pass the col count has it's own scope

```
function k_overide_product_count($cols)
{
    global $myvalue;
    return $myvalue;

}
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'k_overide_product_count', 20 );
```

Comment: Whats the use of a function declaring its intent to use a global value and sending it back as it is without any changes?

Comment: This is WordPress .. the user wants access to a value defined outside the scope of the function